# Finding the wattage given on the bulb

Tags: power, led, ac

Sorry for what might seem like a really simple question. I came across a LED bulb that has the following specs:

[image: GE LED Bulb specs]

It is rated for:

- 120VAC (which I assume is just because the wall voltage in the US is 120VAC @ 60Hz)
- 14W power
- 14mA current

However, I don't know how they calculated 14W if according to the power law equation:

```
P = I * V
```

I should get something like

```
16.8W = .14A * 120V
```

So my question is, where does the **14W** come from if the power equation is **16.8W**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the obvious : "120V" is not always 120V. You need to size wiring, fuses, breakers for maximum current which (in a switching supply) occur at minimum voltage : 14W needs 140mA at 100V.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The power factor is not 1.00 in most electronics, particularly inexpensive low-power electronics, so the product of current and voltage (VA) will, in general, be higher than the real power (W) drawn.

As well, those numbers may be maximums and not nominal so you can't necessarily depend on them to be consistent.

Comment: Be honest. You don’t really know, either. I doubt they’d use VA on something so small, and if they did, they’d *say* VA instead of W.

Comment: @hacktastical  I do know it's not intended to be the wattage delivered to the LEDs. Not sure that's worth all the downvotes you've gotten. Maybe because it was the selected answer. A better answer (not mine) might refer to marking regulations wherever this lamp was sold.

Comment: @hacktastical P.S. the VA I refer to is the calculated product of the marked volts and amperes which is higher than the watts, as expected.

Comment: Cos phi and poor PF would easily account for the difference.

Comment: There should be little doubt that the marked 14W is the real power, the 0.14x120 = 16.8 is the VA and the power factor is 14/16.8 = 0.83. For a product like that, 0.83 ia not really a bad pf. A new bulb that I pulled out of a nearby closet is marked 14.7 W 197mA 120V. That is a 0.62 pf. I have tested some of these before and found that my Kill-A-Watt pf indication matches up with that interpretation of the markings on the bulb. I say Spehro absolutely knows and @Hackastastical absolutely does not.

Answer (score 3):

I examined and tested an LED bulb that I have and found:

Marked: on the bulb 120VAC, 197mA, 14.7W and calculated 23.6VA, 0.62pf

Measured: 121.1VAC, 190mA, 13.2W and calculated 23.0VA, 0.57pf

The discrepancy between watts marked on the bulb and the current marked on the bulb multiplied by the voltage marked on the bulb is due to low power factor caused by harmonic currents drawn by the voltage converter circuit - nothing else.

[image]

[image]